# Fazer get de uma lista de objetos com mensagem personalizada (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, controller

No momento eu consigo retornar a lista de objetos (produtos).

Eu gostaria de mostrar as informações de cada objeto com um texto formatado, por exemplo:
`O produto (nome_produto) tem o preço (preço_produto) que é (descrição_do_produto)`.

```java
@GetMapping("/list/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> listProducts(@PathVariable long id){

    try {
        Optional<Client> searchClient = clientService.getClientById(id);

        if (searchClient.isPresent()) {
            List<Product> wishlist = wishListService.getWishlist(searchClient.get()).getProduct();

            return new ResponseEntity<>(wishlist,HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

    }catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solução rápida e "não usual"

Você pode definir quais campos vai aparecer no retorno da listagem com o json, e pode inclusive gerar novos campos.

Para isso, utilize `@JsonProperty` que vai retornar uma nova propriedade. Nesse caso você pode criar um método get, concatenar a frase que deseja, e o resultado vai ser retornado no json.

Além disso, utilize `@JsonIgnore`para retirar as propriedades que estão sendo retornadas mas que você não deseja no retorno.

## Compreendendo o assunto

Normalmente quando se constrói `API`, ou `microserviço`, e o mesmo é consumido por outro sistema, ou por um módulo frontend, não se usa formatar os dados para enviar para a camada ou aplicativo de `view`.

No próprio `front`, é que normalmente o dado é formatado para responder da forma apropriada ao usuário. Apesar de não ser obrigatório funcionar dessa forma.

Mas isso favorece a reutilização.

Vou dar um exemplo. Imagine uma lista de livros que são retornadas assim:

```js
...
   [
     {"titulo": "livro 1", editora: "X"},
     {"titulo": "livro 2", editora: "Y"},
     {"titulo": "livro 3", editora: "A"},
     {"titulo": "livro 4", editora: "B"}
   ]
```

Imagine que seu serviço retorne da maneira acima.
Dois dispositivos diferentes de views (2 aplicações diferentes, por exemplo um aplicativo de celular e um front web) podem receber esses dados e formatar da maneira apropriada.

Um pode usar os campos separados. Outro pode concatenar em uma frase como você propôs.

Vamos dizer que no app de celular o objetivo seja exibir:
`livro 1 da editora X`

Já no front web, o objetivo seja apresentar assim:
`editora X: livro 1`

Por isso, o mais adequado é o retorno dos dados em formato `JSON`, ou `XML` por exemplo com os devidos valores.